# Localise dynamic text string in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I just started working on localising my iOS app and now I'm facing a few problems that I was hoping somebody could help me out with.

I generated my string file for english and french text using genstrings and its working fine for all static text in my app. However, for dynamic strings, genstrings doesn't create a key in my string file because Im using a variable for the string in the     NSLocalizedString() macro. It gives me error that said string is not a literal string. Which makes sense. Now I'm actually using allot of dynamic data, and some values from parse and core data will be used in my app on runtime.

Pls guide me where I'm wrong, I understand I will have to create keys for all the possible combinations of strings that I will receive in my string file. And depending upon what text I receive, I will have to add checks in my code for every string? If I have 20 combinations of strings coming from parse for a label, I will have 20 checks for that label? Is there an easier approach to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSLocalizedString` should be used with constant 'identifiers' (literals). This ties in with `genstrings` and allows it to generate the .strings file. Preferably, you should set a comment when using `NSLocalizedString` to describe the context + parameters + order so the translator knows what to do.

Now, the .strings file should be updated with the appropriate text and format variables (in the suitable order for the language).

At no point should the format be specified in code. You can't guarantee what, and how many, words there will be around the format parameters in each different language.

An interesting discussion on the topic is at [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/string-localization.html).

Comment: Thanks for the document. It was really helpful! I figure there is no short cut for the localisation to work. I'l have to create keys for every string that might show up and dynamically switch which key i need.
Thanks for your help!